# Sql data retrieval issue

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have below tables:

**Order**

```
Order_id     orde_number    Order_name  

1             12345          iphone

2             67891          samsung
```

**order_event**

```
order_event_no      status

1                    D

1                    C

2                    C
```

I wrote below query to retrieve `status not in ('D')` like below ,But it gave me 2 records ,
But query should not return because `order_no` 1 already as status `D`, even though  it has second record C it should not include.

```
select o.order_number,o.order_name 
  from order o 
  join order_event oe 
    on (o.order_id=oe.order_event_no) where oe.status not in ('D')
```

Regards,
Chaitu

Comment: Is `order_event.status` a mandatory column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will accomplish what you want with your given schema / data...

```
SELECT order_number, order_name
FROM order
WHERE order_id NOT IN (SELECT order_event_no FROM order_event WHERE status = 'D')
```

Comment: Using subqueries may have a performance impact depending on your DBMS, what indexes you have, and the size of data.  But you'd want to profile the explain plan for this against alternative solutions.  I will provide an alternative you could test performance against as an edit to my answer.

Comment: @Jim: Do you have any other alternatives Jim?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exclude any order who has a status like 'D' you need a subquery.

```
select o.order_number,o.order_name 
from order o 
where oe.order_event_no 
NOT IN
    (SELECT order_event_no FROM order_event_no WHERE status = 'D')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is equivalent. Some RDBMs will execute it faster:

```
Select
  o.order_number,
  o.order_name
from
  order o
where
  not exists (
    select
      'x'
    from
      order_event oe
    where
      oe.order_event_no = o.order_id And
      oe.status = 'D'
  );
```